# identify my giant rainier seriel number GK287424

Tags: mountain-bike, giant, serial-number

Please help me with any info on my Giant Rainier, serial number GK287424; it was gifted to me recently.

Comment: What are you trying to find out?

Answer (score 1):

Giant sold a model with this name from 2005 to 2012, so it's a relatively-early 29" hard tail with a triple crankset and quite-decent components.  It is not a BSO or walmart-grade of bike.

[image]
<sub>from https://mtbdatabase.com/bikes/2010/giant/rainier/2010-giant-rainier/</sub>

There was some redesign in 2006, according to https://products.mtbr.com/product/bikes/xc-hardtail/giant/rainier-363498.html

For more general info, start by googling the brand/model and "review"  like this https://www.google.com/search?q=review+giant+rainier  
 If you have more specific questions, ask a new question (with clear photos ideally)